# "Proper Cheerio”: Proper?

Tags: british-english

A call to **BrE** speakers: A television outlet in NE US is advertising a gala fundraising event coinciding with the finale of the *Downton Abbey* television series in the States.

> Sunday, March 6, 2016 marks the end of an era, as Downton Abbey draws the curtain on its final episode.
>   Join Vermont PBS to give the series a proper send-off at this gala finale event!
>   •   Screening of the FULL final episode.
>   •   Reception, hors d’oeuvres & cash bar.
>   •   Jazz-era dancing to the Vermont Jazz Ensemble.
>   •   Downton Abbey photo opportunity!

They've titled their event ***A Proper Cheerio*** - which sounds grating to my untutored ear.  The voiceover announcer is clearly an American making an unfortunate attempt at an RP delivery, as if the organizers are trying to sound like "*poncy toffs*" (an expression for which I am indebted to an EL&U guru) - and falling short.

My question: is ***a proper cheerio*** a *proper* Briticism?

Google and other search engines offer little encouragement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a native BrE speaker, I would have to say that it doesn't sound at all British to me, and I would never say anything like that except as a joke.

*Cheerio* is a little used term now, which is perhaps not an issue in the context of Downton Abbey. Using it as a noun and modifying with 'proper' is really quite bizarre. So much so that [Ngram draws a blank](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Proper%20cheerio&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=). It is certainly not standard BrE usage.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **Yes.** Though I agree that it sounds clumsy.

From context, it's clear that the organisers are deliberately emphasising the Britishness of the event, and do so by using stereotypical British terminology.

The two terms here are :

**cheerio** - informal British slang for a friendly farewell.

**proper** - correct, genuine or appropriate. In a British context this can be a bit nuanced, what's 'proper' depending on one's understanding of the social ettiquite.

For example

> He's wearing a black bow tie to this event? That's not quite proper is it?

While you're correct that 'proper cheerio' isn't a common expression together, proper is a descriptive adjective that can be applied to any noun.

eg.

> A proper job. A proper car. A proper girlfriend. A proper party.

So a proper cheerio does suit here.

I think what makes it sounds clumsy is the use of *cheerio*. Cheerio is a farewell *expression*, not an *event*. What comes to mind when I think of a *proper cheerio* is someone saying the word with gusto and a wave of the hand.

eg.

> The postman gave me a proper cheerio when I finished talking to him this morning, what a swell fellow!

Perhaps what would have made more appropriate for this event would be *a proper send-off*, but of course, that doesn't sound as explicitly British.